# Why does EXCEPT exist in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql

I was just reading about EXCEPT and INTERSECT in the MSDN Library and came across this example of how to use INTERSECT:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2 GO 
SELECT ProductID 
FROM Production.Product
INTERSECT
SELECT ProductID 
FROM Production.WorkOrder ;
--Result: 238 Rows (products that have work orders)
```

Maybe I'm old-fashioned, but I typically would use the following code to achieve the same result:

```
SELECT P.ProductID 
FROM Production.Product P 
INNER JOIN Production.WorkOrder W ON W.ProductID = P.ProductID
```

Am I missing something, or is INTERSECT the same as INNER JOIN?  Is there a performance benefit to using one over the other?

Same question for EXCEPT.  How is this:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
SELECT ProductID 
FROM Production.Product
EXCEPT
SELECT ProductID 
FROM Production.WorkOrder ;
--Result: 266 Rows (products without work orders)
```

different from this:

```
SELECT P.ProductID 
FROM Production.Product P 
LEFT JOIN Production.WorkOrder W ON W.ProductID = P.ProductID
WHERE W.ProductID IS NULL
```

?

Comment: -1: That's not how INTERSECT works. Your first example doesn't return products that have work orders; it returns the ID of any product that has the same id as the id of a work order for a product.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm going to focus on `EXCEPT` just because I'm more familiar with it. Also, as a disclaimer, my examples will be in Sqlite, since I'm on a Linux box. However, both Sqlite and SQL Server should support the functionality.

Both `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT` are set operators, stemming from the underlying ideas in [relational algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Joins_and_join-like_operators). They operate on **distinct values**, being set operators.

Your example is simplistic. I'll give a counterexample, using a Sqlite version of the [Northwind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143221.aspx) sample database.

Let's say that you want to get the CustomerIDs of all customers who made an order with EmployeeID of 5, but NOT those who also made an order with EmployeeID of 6. This is simple and natural with an `EXCEPT`.

```
SELECT CustomerID FROM orders
WHERE EmployeeID = 5
EXCEPT
SELECT CustomerID FROM orders
WHERE EmployeeID = 6
```

This returns 14 rows on my version of Northwind.

Suppose you decide to rewrite this using `JOIN`s. Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT o1.CustomerID
FROM orders o1 INNER JOIN orders o2 ON o1.CustomerID = o2.CustomerID
WHERE o1.EmployeeID = 5 AND o2.EmployeeID != 6
```

Whoops, 525 rows. Maybe add a `DISTINCT`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT o1.CustomerID
FROM orders o1 INNER JOIN orders o2 ON o1.CustomerID = o2.CustomerID
WHERE o1.EmployeeID = 5 AND o2.EmployeeID != 6
```

Now it's 28 rows, still much more than what we were getting with `EXCEPT`. The reason is that this isn't removing CustomerIDs that have made an order with 6. Rather, it returns *all* CustomerIDs that have an order with 5 and *some* EmployeeID other than 6, whether or not they also have an order with EmployeeID 6.

In short, `EXCEPT` and `INTERSECT` are set operators that compare two queries, returning unique tuples, and certainly have their use.

Comment: You can write code like this                                     select o1.CustomerId from
(
select CustomerId from orders where EmployeeID = 5
) as o1
left outer join 
(
 select CustomerID from orders where EmployeeID = 6
) as o2
on o1.CustomerID = o2.CustomerID
where o2.CustomerID is null

Answer (score 23):

- INTERSECT and EXCEPT are semi-joins
- JOIN is equi-join

So when you join 2 tables that match, say, 5 rows and 3 rows

- JOIN gives 15 rows
- INTERSECT gives 3 rows

EXCEPT is similar to OUTER JOIN for the same reason

While we're on about semi-joins, then *mostly*

- INTERSECT gives the same results as EXISTS
- EXCEPT gives the same results as NOT EXISTS

The "mostly" comes because both INTERSECT and EXCEPT

- treat NULL differently: For a fully worked example, see [this by Paul White aka SQL Kiwi](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx)
- apply DISTINCT

Edit, Quick demo of all this

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (t1col INT);
INSERT @t1 VALUES (1), (2), (2), (3), (3), (5), (5);

DECLARE @t2 TABLE (t2col INT);
INSERT @t2 VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);

SELECT 'INNER JOIN', * FROM @t1 t1 JOIN @t2 t2 ON t1.t1col = t2.t2col -- same both ways

SELECT 't1 INTERSECT t2', * FROM @t1 INTERSECT SELECT 't1 INTERSECT t2', * FROM @t2;

SELECT 't2 INTERSECT t1', * FROM @t2 INTERSECT SELECT 't2 INTERSECT t1', * FROM @t1;

SELECT 't1 EXISTS t2', * FROM @t1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @t2 t2 WHERE t1.t1col = t2.t2col);

SELECT 't2 EXISTS t1', * FROM @t2 t2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @t1 t1 WHERE t1.t1col = t2.t2col);

SELECT 't1 LEFT JOIN t2, IS NULL', * FROM @t1 t1 LEFT JOIN @t2 t2 ON t1.t1col = t2.t2col WHERE t2.t2col IS NULL
SELECT 't2 LEFT JOIN t1, IS NULL', * FROM @t2 t2 LEFT JOIN @t1 t1 ON t1.t1col = t2.t2col WHERE t1.t1col IS NULL

SELECT 't1 EXCEPT t2', * FROM @t1 EXCEPT SELECT 't1 EXCEPT t2', * FROM @t2;

SELECT 't2 EXCEPT t1', * FROM @t2 EXCEPT SELECT 't2 EXCEPT t1', * FROM @t1;

SELECT 't1 NOT EXISTS t2', * FROM @t1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @t2 t2 WHERE t1.t1col = t2.t2col);

SELECT 't2 NOT EXISTS t1', * FROM @t2 t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @t1 t1 WHERE t1.t1col = t2.t2col);
```

Update: Feb 2013. Added extra column to describe the operation

Comment: @Mikael Eriksson: I'm wrong, fixed. I didn't have a good enough demo script before

Comment: Actually, looking back, isn't `EXCEPT` an [antijoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Joins_and_join-like_operators), not a semijoin?

Comment: @voithos yes and no! EXCEPT = left anti semi join, INTERSECT = left semi join. De-duplicate (hence compare) comes from the semi-join. The anti-join part is the difference is the difference between them (include or exclude matching rows)

Answer (score 1):

Your examples of your "equivalent" queries are wrong - the query with `INTERSECT` not always return the same result as `INNER JOIN` and the same for `EXCEPT` and `LEFT JOIN`.

Look at particular example about INTERSECT:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(t INT NOT NULL)
DECLARE @x TABLE(x INT NOT NULL)

INSERT @t
VALUES (1), (2), (3)

INSERT @x VALUES(1), (1), (1)

SELECT t FROM @t
INTERSECT SELECT x FROM @x

SELECT t FROM @t
INNER JOIN @x ON x = t
```

`INTERSECT` is more like (**but not the same**) as `IN` clause:

```
SELECT t FROM @t
WHERE t IN (select x FROM @x)
```

or as `EXISTS`

```
SELECT t FROM @t
WHERE EXISTS (select * FROM @x WHERE x = t)
```

**The same examples you may adapt to `EXCEPT` clause.**

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion `EXCEPT` and `INTERSECT` are used to do the same things as the JOIN command, but it simpler with tables that don't have Primary Keys, for example:

with `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME,
       LASTNAME,
       ADDRESSLINE1,
       CITY,
       STATEPROVINCECODE,
       POSTALCODE
FROM   MANAGER 
EXCEPT
SELECT FIRSTNAME,
       LASTNAME,
       ADDRESSLINE1,
       CITY,
       STATEPROVINCECODE,
       POSTALCODE
FROM   CUSTOMER
```

And to have the same results with JOIN, you must do:

```
SELECT   M.FIRSTNAME,
         M.LASTNAME,
         M.ADDRESSLINE1,
         M.CITY,
         M.STATEPROVINCECODE,
         M.POSTALCODE
FROM     MANAGER M
WHERE    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM   CUSTOMER C
                     WHERE  M.FIRSTNAME = C.FIRSTNAME
                            AND M.LASTNAME = C.LASTNAME
                            AND M.ADDRESSLINE1 = C.ADDRESSLINE1
                            AND M.CITY = C.CITY
                            AND M.POSTALCODE = C.POSTALCODE)
GROUP BY M.FIRSTNAME,M.LASTNAME,M.ADDRESSLINE1,M.CITY,
         M.STATEPROVINCECODE,M.POSTALCODE
```

More information [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1327/compare-sql-server-datasets-with-intersect-and-except/).