# SQL select column with same key if all values are null

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have two columns , ColumnA and ColumnB, occassionally columnB doesnt gets populated and it should e.  I'm looking for a query that will only select if all ColumnA is unpopulated.

```
ColumnA|ColumnB
Apples|
Apples|
Apples|Orange
```

This is what i'm but this is incorrect because it says ColumnA is null with the same value and ColumnB is populated.  I want the query only to return rows if all of columnB is unpopulated.

```
SELECT ColumnA
 FROM tblMyTable
WHERE ColumnA IN
      (SELECT ColumnA 
         FROM tblMyTableB
        WHERE ColumnB IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 3):

You current query gives you too many results. The ones you want to eliminate are those where there *is* a `ColumnB` value:

```
SELECT ColumnA
 FROM tblMyTable
WHERE ColumnA IN
      (SELECT ColumnA 
         FROM tblMyTableB
        WHERE ColumnB IS NULL)
AND NOT ColumnA IN
      (SELECT ColumnA 
         FROM tblMyTableB
        WHERE ColumnB IS NOT NULL)
```

Or, smarter is:

```
select ColumnA,COUNT(ColumnB) from tblMyTable
group by ColumnA having COUNT(ColumnB) = 0
```

Because [`COUNT(Expression)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) only counts non-null expression values

Comment: @MarkBannister - yeah, first was more of a "quick and dirty, should work". It took me a few tries to get the second one right (sorry I posted around the same time yours was being written)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your logic is backwards:

- Your query finds values in column A where there *is* a NULL value in column B.
- I think you want the values in column A where there *isn't* a *non-NULL* value in column B.

Try adding `NOT` in two places and add `DISTINCT` to avoid getting duplicate results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA
FROM tblMyTable
WHERE ColumnA NOT IN
      (SELECT ColumnA 
       FROM tblMyTableB
       WHERE ColumnB IS NOT NULL)
```

In addition, if `ColumnA` can be NULL then you'll have to exclude those NULL values from your inner query otherwise the `NOT IN` expression will return `NULL` instead of `True` and so no results will be returned:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA
FROM tblMyTable
WHERE ColumnA NOT IN
      (SELECT ColumnA 
       FROM tblMyTableB
       WHERE ColumnA IS NOT NULL
       AND ColumnB IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: No because I only want to find the instances of where columnB is null  for all values that are in ColumnA

Answer (score 0):

Using EXCEPT. This can be expressed as

> Get Column A, EXCEPT where some non-null in Column B for that column A

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (ColumnA varchar(20) NOT NULL, ColumnB varchar(20) NULL);

INSERT @MyTable VALUES
  ('Apple', NULL),('Apple', NULL),('Apple', 'Orange'),
  ('Banana', NULL),('Banana', NULL), 
  ('Strawberry', 'Pie'), ('Strawberry', 'Pie')

SELECT ColumnA FROM @MyTable
EXCEPT
SELECT ColumnA FROM @MyTable WHERE ColumnB IS NOT NULL
```

More on EXCEPT: [Why does EXCEPT exist in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107022/why-does-except-exist-in-t-sql/9109441#9109441)