# Why does UNION returns only one null?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null

I understand `null` represents missing/unknown value, so a `null` is not equal to another `null` because two unknown things cannot be compared. For example

```
if null = null
    select 'nulls are equal'
else
    select 'nulls are not equal'
```

results in `'nulls are not equal'` I used an `=` instead of `is null` or `is not null` here to emphasize the fact that two nulls cannot be compared.

Coming to `UNION`, `UNION` is supposed to eliminate duplicate values. I was expecting the below code to return two rows each with `null` since two `null` values are not equal, but I get only one null in the result set.

```
(select null as Col1)
union 
(select null as Col1)
```

Why does SQL's interpretation of 'null as an unknown value' change in above two statements?

Comment: Very good question. But that's how it is.. Even `Distinct` does the same..May be `UNION` and `DISTINCT` uses `IS` operator internally to compare

Comment: @Mihai-DanielVirna, I experimented with UNION ALL. UNION ALL returns two null rows.

Comment: If you do `null is null` instead of using equal it will yield `true`

Comment: @Mihai-DanielVirna, Thanks. I modified my question to explain why I used an = instead of is/is not null.

Comment: Is it that two nulls cannot be compared?  I vaguely recall reading somewhere that if either side of an equality is NULL, SQL Server automatically returns false, without even evaluating the other side. Senility is setting in fast though  .. my memory is not what it once was :-(

Comment: @Pரதீப் maybe, INTERSECT and EXCEPT definitely do. See my answer below

Comment: `NULL` is `NULL`, so they get grouped by together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NULL is not comparable, but SQL generally does have the concept of "IS DISTINCT FROM"
SQL Server has a [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/286422/add-language-and-optimizer-support-for-iso-distinct-predicate) item for it

- `1` IS DISTINCT FROM `NULL` = true
- `1 = null` is false

For completeness, `NULL` IS DISTINCT FROM `NULL` = false

I would guess that DISTINCT and UNION use `IS DISTINCT FROM` (as Pரதீப் mentioned above)

Now, SQL Server **does** have `IS DISTINCT FROM` in INTERSECT and EXCEPT

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (t1col INT);
INSERT @t1 VALUES (1), (NULL), (2), (3), (3), (5), (5);

DECLARE @t2 TABLE (t2col INT);
INSERT @t2 VALUES (1), (NULL), (3), (4);

SELECT DISTINCT 't1 EXISTS t2', * 
FROM @t1 t1 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @t2 t2 WHERE t1.t1col = t2.t2col);

t1 EXISTS t2    1
t1 EXISTS t2    3
t1 EXISTS t2    3

SELECT DISTINCT 't1 INTERSECT t2', *
FROM @t1 INTERSECT SELECT 't1 INTERSECT t2', * FROM @t2;

t1 INTERSECT t2 NULL
t1 INTERSECT t2 1
t1 INTERSECT t2 3
```

INTERSECT and EXCEPT also remove duplicates because they do a semi-join
EXISTS is an anti-join BTW

For completeness

```
SELECT 't1 EXISTS t2', * 
FROM @t1 t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @t2 t2 WHERE t1.t1col = t2.t2col);

t1 EXISTS t2    NULL
t1 EXISTS t2    2
t1 EXISTS t2    5
t1 EXISTS t2    5

SELECT 't1 EXCEPT t2', * 
FROM @t1 EXCEPT SELECT 't1 EXCEPT t2', * FROM @t2;

t1 EXCEPT t2    2
t1 EXCEPT t2    5
```

Example taken from my answer [Why does EXCEPT exist in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107022/why-does-except-exist-in-t-sql/9109441#9109441) with added NULLs

Comment: It really took some time to understand. Never know `1 IS DISTINCT FROM NULL` exists once ;)..Nice answer as usual

Answer (score 2):

`UNION` is basically `SELECT DISTINCT`, so it would be eliminating duplicate NULL values, but it's not the same as Equal operation.

Using `UNION ALL` would give you all records including duplicating NULLs.

As for the first part of you question. NULL really equals NULL, but not with "=". This would give you result you expect:

```
if null IS null
select 'nulls are equal'
else
select 'nulls are not equal'
```

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql) is also helpful when dealing with nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Try UNION ALL to retain everything in both sets without removing duplicates.