# Why using SQL UPDATE() function along with Inserted table is not working in this after update trigger?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, database-trigger

I have found a couple of similar questions in here that I have used to try solving this case, but nothing seems to work for me.
So, basically I have a Pallet table, and I need to change Status field when Loaded field changes to a value <> to what it was or <> to *NULL*, and Status is also different. The trigger is basically doing nothing. So, I have:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TR_Status_Change]
   ON [dbo].[Pallet]
   AFTER UPDATE
AS BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF UPDATE (Loaded)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [Pallet] 
        SET PStatus = 3
        FROM [Pallet] P 
        INNER JOIN Inserted I ON P.ID = I.ID
        WHERE P.PStatus <> 3
            AND P.Loaded <> I.Loaded
            AND I.Loaded IS NOT NULL
    END
END
```

Where ID is primary key. Row values are as follows:

```
before update: Loaded = NULL, Status = 1

after: Loaded = 'somevalue' and Status remains = 1

expected: Status = 3
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Something compared to NULL" comparisons are always false so this fails

```
AND P.Loaded <> I.Loaded
```

Try this. You need both "before" and "after" values of Loaded too

```
UPDATE [Pallet] 
    SET PStatus = 3
    FROM [Pallet] P 
    INNER JOIN Deleted D ON P.ID = D.ID
    INNER JOIN Inserted I ON P.ID = I.ID
    WHERE P.PStatus <> 3
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT I.Loaded INTERSECT SELECT D.Loaded)
        AND I.Loaded IS NOT NULL
```

INTERSECT internally does a "is different from" comparison, not equality. If they are different, the intersect gives no rows, so NOT EXISTS gives true

For more on INTERSECT and EXCEPT, please see my answer here [Why does EXCEPT exist in T-SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107022/why-does-except-exist-in-t-sql/9109441#9109441)

Comment: Fixed that for you. *""Something compared to NULL" comparisons are always f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶ unknown"*

Comment: @Larnu: and unknown equates to false in the WHERE clause. `SELECT 'who cares if unknown' WHERE 1 = NULL OR 1 = 1` . Good enough

Comment: @gbn so, it will always be necessary to include Deleted table in similar cases and no comparison operator can be used, right??

Comment: yes, always need "Deleted". And you can use comparison operators on non-null columns. But this INTERSECT trick works anyway if you want to be consistent

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thing:
`P.Loaded <> I.Loaded`

This will never be true, because you are comparing the data of the table after the update ([Pallet P]) with....the data that of the table after the update (Inserted I).

I think you want to change Inserted I to the deleted table, which holds the values BEFORE the update operation.